# if condition in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a tow table name t1,t2 . Based on the value insert in t1 i want to insert in t2 .
i use the following trigger .

```
create trigger testt after insert on t1
BEGIN
for each row
if NEW.uid='Mill' then insert into t2 (uid2) values (NEW.uid)
end if
 if NEW.uid='Farm' then insert into t2 (uid2) values (NEW.r)
end if
END
```

Please help me to resolve this issue . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just have some keywords out of order:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: just for reference i added that BEGIN and END keyword , Actually i haven't use that .

Comment: Why did you include keywords that you haven't used?  It's hard to answer a question by mind-reading.  Please edit your question and be clear about what you *actually* tried, and what the issue is that you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
create trigger testt after insert on t1
BEGIN
for each row BEGIN
if NEW.uid='Mill' then insert into t2 (uid2) values (NEW.uid)
end if
 if NEW.uid='Farm' then insert into t2 (uid2) values (NEW.r)
end if
END
```